EXACT same parameters in Uniswap V3Router yielding different results
params=
{"tokenIn":"0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006","tokenOut":"0x833589fcd6edb6e08f4c7c32d4f71b54bda02913","fee":"100","recipient":"0x2834450b955c32728aa8d0d7d84f3072a5395629","amountIn":"10000000000000","amountOutMinimum":"10000","sqrtPriceLimitX96":"0"}) => (3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944)

params =
{"amountIn":"10000000000000","amountOutMinimum":"10000","fee":"100","recipient":"0x2834450b955c32728aa8d0d7d84f3072a5395629","sqrtPriceLimitX96":"0","tokenIn":"0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006","tokenOut":"0x833589fcd6edb6e08f4c7c32d4f71b54bda02913"}) => (31157)

The following parameters were collected from the debugger at tenderly, for the transactions:
0xf76c7d4f684d9ee6132fd75c92ee09a42be491382b4bf8b1570f16a4881320dc
and
0x04a1d209f005aaf5d9fff3ed2fd0ff0901edfba0a05e22d2deacb342697dd567
These are effectively the same transactions, except the first is being sent from my machine in an EthersJS script.
The script is as follows:
  const params = {
    tokenIn: CurrentConfig.tokens.in.address,
    tokenOut: CurrentConfig.tokens.out.address,
    fee: 100,
    recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
    amountIn: 10000000000000,
    amountOutMinimum: 422,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
  }
  
  /* @ts-ignore */
  swapRouterContract.connect(connectedWallet).exactInputSingle(
    params,
    {
      gasLimit: BigInt(GAS_LIMIT)
    }
  ).then((transaction: any) => {
    console.log(transaction)
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

While the other is being performed at BaseScan:

I'm at a loss as of what might be the issue. The only difference I can see between the function calls is the ordering of the arguments, and the strange return value on the first one.
